# Indices that KFold split method return for a DataFrame is it iloc or loc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

When we use `_KFold.split(X)` where X is a DataFrame, the indices that gets generated to split data into training and test set, is it `iloc` (Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position) or is it `loc` (loc of group of rows and columns by label(s))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select rows by positions:

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
#changed default index values
df.index = df.index * 10
print (df)
           A         B         C         D         E
0   0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719
10  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093
20  0.891322  0.209202  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
30  0.978624  0.811683  0.171941  0.816225  0.274074
40  0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112  0.175410
50  0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
60  0.598843  0.603805  0.105148  0.381943  0.036476
70  0.890412  0.980921  0.059942  0.890546  0.576901
80  0.742480  0.630184  0.581842  0.020439  0.210027
90  0.544685  0.769115  0.250695  0.285896  0.852395
```

---

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

#added some parameters
kf = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 2)
kf_split = kf.split(df) 
result = next(kf_split)
print (result)
(array([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([1, 4]))

train = df.iloc[result[0]]
test =  df.iloc[result[1]]

print (train)
           A         B         C         D         E
0   0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719
20  0.891322  0.209202  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
30  0.978624  0.811683  0.171941  0.816225  0.274074
50  0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
60  0.598843  0.603805  0.105148  0.381943  0.036476
70  0.890412  0.980921  0.059942  0.890546  0.576901
80  0.742480  0.630184  0.581842  0.020439  0.210027
90  0.544685  0.769115  0.250695  0.285896  0.852395

print (test)
           A         B         C         D         E
10  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093
40  0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112  0.175410
```

Comment: Thank you. So you mean to say that the indices that are returned are iloc NOT loc ?

Comment: @TempO'rary - yes, exactly.